# Multiple bind variables with custom types in oracledb Python

Tags: python, oracle, python-oracledb

So, I'm working in a project that haves multiple output vars for stored procedures, but the types of the vars are custom, with [oracledb](https://oracle.github.io/python-oracledb/) library to declare the output bind variable you have to call:

```
cursor.var(oracledb.OBJECT, typename='custom_type_name')
```

but calling that makes the library fetch type info from db, so here comes the problem, if you have like 50 bind variables with custom types python have to make 50 request to db and that translates to 50 seconds of execution time, how can I improve that?

I tried multithreading and the results are the same.

Comment: Are all of the types different?

Comment: Yes, they are different.

Comment: Then there is currently no way to improve that. But it shouldn't take a second for each one unless you have high latency in your connection to the database!

Comment: Try and do as much processing as possible in PL/SQL to minimize type and data transfers to Python.